# Highlighting Pie Chart Slice When Clicked in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to highlight (change color) of a pie graph specific slice when clicked by the user.
I can find in the samples (the code below) that it is possible to show the index of the slice and the exact point. but what about recoloring the slice ?

```
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast
                .makeText(PieChartBuilder.this, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                PieChartBuilder.this,
                "Chart element data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex()
                    + " was clicked" + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the stuff you need:

```
mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(seriesSelection.getPointIndex()).setColor(color);
mChartView.repaint();
```

Comment: where so we need to add this ?

Comment: Next to the code in the question. See this: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/PieChartBuilder.java

Answer (score 1):

Code for onClick on the chart:

Use this:

```
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(PieChartBuilder.this, "No chart element selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mSeries.getItemCount(); i++) {
              mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setHighlighted(i == seriesSelection.getPointIndex());
            }
            mChartView.repaint();
            Toast.makeText(
                PieChartBuilder.this,
                "Chart data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " selected"
                    + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to ensure the chart is clickable. I spent quite some time wondering why I couldnt get it to work. the line

```
mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
```

should be included